# sound - sorry!, but can't get sound on fresh 14.04 install

Tags: 14.04, sound

New install of 14.04. Motherboard is ASUS Z97 WS with integrated sound.

Alsa-info:
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=397aa78fea90ab7a37b292269b1d949610f5fc3b

Getting zero output from speakers and headphones.
From what I can see, everything looks to be working properly...
In pavucontrol I see under the Playback tab everything that is supposed to be playing sound is listed and appears to be working properly. And nothing muted.
Headphones are recognized when plugged in.

gnome-alsamixer shows nothing muted.

I've tried many of the things suggested here. No luck.

I don't know what to try at this point.

Any ideas, anyone??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried reinstalling the pulse audio? There was another post sometime ago , where a guy deleted .pulseaudio folder in his home directory and after reboot it worked.  I'll try to find it and reference here

Comment: OK found it in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio . Quote " . . .if the system outputs no sound, it may be necessary to delete the contents of ~/.config/pulse and/or ~/.pulse. PulseAudio will automatically create new configuration files on its next start. " Also , take a peek here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure . And for worst case scenario (dead sound card) , you can get a external usb sound card - there are some like 15$ on amazon

Comment: @Xieerqi, thanks for the info. from my comment below, I need to look into this further. If I find anything more I'll post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the console-based program `alsamixer`, and make sure nothing is muted (which is indicated by two capital M's located just above the level indicators at the bottom). Press <kbd>m</kbd> to toggle mute.

If that doesn't help, try running `alsamixer -D pulse`and making sure that isn't muted either.

Comment: Something is afoot! I went to bed last night angry after fighting this sound issue for a couple days. Woke up this morning and powered up Ubuntu and dang if I don't have sound. I haven't had much time to play with this tonight but one thing I think is involved is doing complete reboot as opposed to a restart. It seems to be working every time from a start from a complete shutdown. But sometimes (not always) is does not work after a restart. Now, this machine is a dual Win8.1/Ubuntu system and I may have noticed that it never works from restarting from Win8.1. Hmmmmmm!!!